# "Risk" meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I’d like to help you, but I can’t risk losing my job.

According to [Cambridge Essential British Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-british-english/risk) "risk" (v.)  means:

> If you risk something bad, you do something although that bad thing might happen.

I am confused as to **what the phrase "do something" refers to here?**

Comment: In the first sentence, "risk" is used in the sense of *to put yourself in danger*. In the sense of the quoted definition, "risking something" means *taking the risk of doing something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I’d like to help you, but I can’t risk losing my job.

The "something" in **do something**, for the speaker of this sentence is "helping you".

The "bad thing might happen" is for the speaker to **lose their job**.

The speaker risks (something bad) if they (do something).

**The speaker risks losing their job if they help you.**

Comment: Yes, but what's your opinion about ("He risked losing his house when his company went bankrupt.") this sentence.

Comment: @Sam That's a perfectly good sentence. What's your opinion about it (although you're better asking a new question if you have another question)?

Answer (score -1):

In your example sentence, it's not stated what "do something" means. In the context, the person the speaker is talking to probably asked them to *do something* that would put their job in danger. Without more context, we cannot know what that something is.